# Can an index be created on a UUID Column?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-2.0

Is it possible to create an index on a UUID/TIMEUUID column in Cassandra?  I'm testing out a model design which would have an index on a UUID column, but queries on that column always return 0 rows found.

I have a table like this:

```
create table some_data (site_id int, user_id int, run_id uuid, value int, primary key((site_id, user_id), run_id));
```

I create an index with this command:

```
create index idx on some_data (run_id) ;
```

No errors are thrown by CQL when I create this index.

I have a small bit of test data in the table:

```
 site_id | user_id | run_id                               | value
---------+---------+--------------------------------------+-----------------
       1 |       1 | 9e118af0-ac92-11e4-81ae-8d1bc921f26d |               3
```

However, when I run the query:

```
select * from some_data where run_id = 9e118af0-ac92-11e4-81ae-8d1bc921f26d
```

CQLSH just returns:  `(0 rows)`

If I use an `int` for the `run_id` then the index behaves as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can create a secondary index on a UUID.  The real question is "should you?"

In any case, I followed your steps, and got it to work.

```
Connected to Test Cluster at 192.168.23.129:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.2 | CQL spec 3.2.0 | Native protocol v3]
Use HELP for help.
aploetz@cqlsh> use stackoverflow ;
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> create table some_data (site_id int, user_id int, run_id uuid, value int, primary key((site_id, user_id), run_id));
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> create index idx on some_data (run_id) ;
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> INSERT INTO some_data (site_id, user_id, run_id, value) VALUES (1,1,9e118af0-ac92-11e4-81ae-8d1bc921f26d,3);
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> select * from usr_rec3 where run_id = 9e118af0-ac92-11e4-81ae-8d1bc921f26d;
code=2200 [Invalid query] message="unconfigured columnfamily usr_rec3"
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> select * from some_data where run_id = 9e118af0-ac92-11e4-81ae-8d1bc921f26d;

 site_id | user_id | run_id                               | value
---------+---------+--------------------------------------+-------
       1 |       1 | 9e118af0-ac92-11e4-81ae-8d1bc921f26d |     3

(1 rows)
```

Notice though, that when I ran this command, it failed:

```
select * from usr_rec3 where run_id = 9e118af0-ac92-11e4-81ae-8d1bc921f26d
```

Are you sure that you didn't mean to select from `some_data` instead?

Also, creating secondary indexes on high-cardinality columns (like a UUID) is generally not a good idea.  If you need to query by `run_id`, then you should revisit your data model and come up with an appropriate query table to serve that.

**Clarification:**

- Using secondary indexes in general is not considered good practice.  In the new book [Cassandra High Availability](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1783989122), Robbie Strickland identifies their use as an anti-pattern, due to poor performance.
- Just because a column is of the UUID data type doesn't necessarily make it high-cardinality.  That's more of a data model question for you.  But knowing the nature of UUIDs and their underlying purpose toward being unique, is setting off red flags.
- Put these two points together, and there isn't anything about creating an index on a UUID that sounds appealing to me.  If it were my cluster, and (more importantly) I had to support it later, I wouldn't do it.

Comment: Oops, that usr_rec3 was a copy paste error, I was changing the names to make it clearer without lots of context :)